# VM/guest loses internet connectivity when host is connected to VPN

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, vpn, hyper-v-manager

I'm currently running Win10 Pro v21H2, and I have a Hyper-V VM (gen 1) running Win10 Home v21H2. For my remote work, I use Check Point Endpoint Security to connect to my office VPN. I just discovered today that when my host rig is connected to the VPN, the guest VM completely loses internet connectivity. I tinkered a bit with what settings I could think of that could possible solve the issue (network card settings, connection sharing, etc.), but nothing worked, so I restored everything back to the way it was.

I only have one wifi connection on my host rig, so is there any way I could possibly make it so that the VM doesn't lose internet access when the host is on the VPN without, say, adding a second network connection?

Comment: Is your VPN non-Split Tunnel so that is closes off Internet and you get Host Internet through the tunnel?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Checking the VPN settings panel has an option listed as VPN Tunneling with two checkboxes, both unchecked: "Encrypt all traffic and route to gateway" and "Do not route traffic for local network to the gateway". Both options are grayed out so I can't change them anyway. I'll admit this is my first time working with VPNs so I'm a little out of my depth here.

Comment: You need to check with your office to see if settings can be adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of tinkering, I think I figured out a solution.

I went into the Properties of the wifi network adapter... [image: Context menu for wifi network adapter]

...and on the Sharing tab, I enabled Internet Connection Sharing and specified the Hyper-V network adapter as the other device enabled to use the internet through it.

[image: Internet connection sharing]

This allowed me to have the guest OS connected to the internet without touching IP settings or anything in the VM while still being able to keep the host OS connected to the VPN.

Hope this is useful for someone else as well.